# `page-break` for content inside iFrames

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I noticed that `page-break-after` and `page-break-before` do not work for content that inside iFrames. Is there a known workaround or any other approach to do page breaks inside iFrames?

Comment: Have you tried multiple browsers? This seems to be an issue in chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=136070

Comment: Hey 735Tesla,
1. Since I am using puppeteer, I can only use chrome.
2. Thanks for the link to the bug. But that bug has been closed and marked as a duplicate of https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135563 whose status is Fixed.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the behavior today. You're right about the fixed dup, though I'm I could imagine a fixed minor bug in chromium could still persist in chrome